# Get options of VBA Dialogs(xlDialogSort)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I need to implement the same sorting on several sheets. Moreover, I want user to set sorting rules manually using standard Sort dialog window.

So, I want to create a procedure that will initiate Dialogs(xlDialogSort) window, and after user has specified sorting parameteres and clicked OK, procedure will "read" those parameters and apply them to several sheets through the macro (standard sorting code).

Currently my code looks like the following:

```
Public Sub sortMultipleSheets()
    Dim sortDiagAnswer As Boolean

    sortDiagAnswer = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSort).Show

    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        MsgBox "Place the cursor in the area to be sorted"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Err.Clear

    If sortDiagAnswer Then
        'read user defined parameters
        '...

        actualSort (wsh1)
        actualSort (wsh2)
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub actualSort(ByVal wsh As Worksheet)
    With wsh.Sort
        With .SortFields
            .Clear
            .Add Key:= 'user-defined key1
            .Add Key:= 'user-defined key2
            .Add Key:= 'user-defined key3
            'any more user-defined keys
        End With
        .SetRange Range('actual range)
        .Header = 'setting from the sorting dialog window
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

I am missing the part that will obtain user defined parameters on hitting OK button. 
Any ideas please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't get parameters from a dialog box. You can send in parameters with the Show method, but they must be ByVal because they don't change. Sort and Find (and maybe some others) arguments persist from one call to the other. That means the next time you sort the same range, the dialog will remember what you did the previous time. Normally that's dangerous from a code perspective, but you can use it to your advantage here.

```
Dim srt As Sort

If Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSort).Show Then
    Set srt = ActiveSheet.Sort
    Debug.Print srt.SortFields(1).Key.Address
End If
```

Whatever the user selects for the key of the first sort field will be print to the Immediate Window. You can get at any properties of the Sort object right after the dialog closes to see what was selected. Obviously to put together a whole picture will be more complicated than the code above.

Comment: great, thanks! Finally, I got time to apply your code to my needs. Works like a charm