# Using VBA for Showing/Opening Excel built-in dialog

Tags: excel, vba, dialog

When Using

```
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogRun).Show
```

It shows the Macro Dialog (xlDialogRun) ?

```
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogMacroOptions).Show
```

Is not working. Show method of Dialog class failed

Same, I need to open/show the Sort Dialog

```
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSort).Show
```

Is not working. Show method of Dialog class failed.

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Sort.SortDialog
```

Is not working. Object does not support this property or method.

Excel 2021, VBA 7.1, Windows 11, 64 Bit

[XlBuiltInDialog enumeration (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.XlBuiltInDialog)

Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library Installed.

From the VBE menu, select View > Object Browser
Then Set Libraries to Excel
Search for XlBuiltInDialog to display the Members of "XlBuiltInDialog"

Show all the Dialogs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People have mentioned needing to name the macro you're trying to get the options dialog for like so `Application.Dialogs(xlDialogMacroOptions).Show ("yourMacro")` and for the sort dialog, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33399237/19353309).

Some `.Show` require arguments or a previous action. Try to play around and for the arguments: see [this github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/VBA-Docs/blob/main/excel/Concepts/Controls-DialogBoxes-Forms/built-in-dialog-box-argument-lists.md)

Also see [these examples on how to use the arguments to already change certain checkboxes in a dialogbox](https://excelatfinance.com/xlf/xlf-xl-built-in-dialog.php)

Answer (score 0):

What works is

```
    Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim rng As Range
Dim ac As Range

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects(1)
Set rng = tbl.Range
Set ac = ActiveCell

    rng.Select
    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSort).Show
    ac.Select
```